# SVG animation using stroke-dashoffset doesn't display in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, svg

I have the following SVG animation that works perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox but the line drawing doesn't display in IE.
I tried just the line drawing without the fade or moving away from the css shorthands but no change.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpL4okys/

```
      .path {
        stroke:#fff;
        fill:transparent;
        stroke-width:1;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s linear forwards, fadeout 1.9s linear;
                animation: dash 1.5s linear forwards, fadeout 1.9s linear;
      }
      .drawing {
        position: relative;
      }
      .illustration, .line-drawing {
        position: absolute;
        top:20%;
        left:0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
      }
      .illustration {
        opacity: 1;
        animation: fadein 2s ease-in;
      }
      @keyframes dash {
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
      }
      @keyframes fadeout {
        0% {
          opacity:1;
        }
        99% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      @keyframes fadein {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        90% {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: I work on mac so I use browserstack to test it, it only says the latest.

Comment: I managed to make it work using https://animejs.com but still would like to know if stroke-dashoffset works in IE

Comment: I try to make a test with your code in IE 11 and looks like it is working. https://i.postimg.cc/3xfw7380/26.gif I suggest you to make a test with IE 11 instead of using browser stack may help you to get accurate result. I also made a test with the sample code of stroke-dashoffset, Which also worked with IE 11. I can see that you had solved your issue using anime.js I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and mark it as an answer after 24 hrs nay help other community members in future in similar kind of issues.

Comment: IE does not support CSS animation of SVG elements.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank for trying but the animation has 2 elements, first the line drawing using stroke-dashoffset, then the fade in for the actual image. This line drawing doesn't display on your test.